# Allowing Users to Add Additional Options to Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a Google Forms poll where the options are user-generated (just like the old Facebook Questions polls, before they were taken away). So a user can either vote for one of the options that's already listed, or add an "other" option, which will then show up for other users to vote on.

I'm using this code based on one I found in a Google discussion group:

```
function addOption(e) {
  try {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formResponse = e.response;
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      var id = itemResponse.getItem().getId();
      var item = form.getItemById(id).asMultipleChoiceItem();
      var choices = item.getChoices();
      choices.push( item.createChoice(itemResponse.getResponse()) );
      item.setChoices(choices);
    }
  } catch (err) { Logger.log(err); }
}
```

It adds user-generated options to the list, as expected, but now if you vote on one of the existing options, it adds a duplicate of the option you voted for.

[image: In this example]

In this example, the first time around, I voted for `Other` in both questions and added options `Test 1.1` and `Test 2.1`. On the second time around, I voted for `Option 1` in the first question and `Test 2.1` in the second question.

I'm not sure how I would check if an option already exists, and add the vote to the already-existing option. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to do it? How?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Item ID:

```
var id = itemResponse.getItem().getId();
var item = form.getItemById(id).asMultipleChoiceItem();
```

You should record the Item ID somewhere, as the Item ID that you want to add the option to will never change for the Form, unless you deleted the question, and added another question back.  You can hard code the ID as a constant, or store the ID in the document properties with PropertiesService.